# Minimum displacement of iid random walks

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-walk

Consider $m$ iid symmetric random walks on the integers that start at the origin. Let $D^i_x$ be the distance of the $i$th walk from the origin after $x$ steps. For a given $x$, what is $E[\min_{1\leq i \leq m} D_x^i]$, that is, what is the minimum distance of a random walk from the origin from among the $m$ walks? Is there a nice asymptotic approximation for this expression?

Comment: Independent, yes, as mentioned in the title (and now also in the text!)

Comment: What does "asymptotic approximation" mean here?  Fixed $x$ and $m\to\infty$, or what?

Comment: @kimchilover Yes, fixed $x$ and $m$ large

Comment: See why the following is true : $D^i_x + x$ is distributed as $2Bin(x,\frac 12)$ for each time step $x\in \mathbb N$? You can reduce your question to a minimum of binomial random variables this way, and for the Binomial expressions may be available.